# how to call another function for the first time only in a recursive function call?

Tags: c

i want to call "function2();" only for single time when recurfunc() was called for the first time.

```
recurfunc()
{
    function2();     //to be called first time only in a recursive function
    static int i= 0;
    i++;

    if(i>20)
        return;
    else
    recurfunc();
}
```

Comment: It really helps everyone (including you) when you use proper indentation.

Comment: i want to implement ls(file listing command)in c and want to check whether user has provided forward slash at the end of the path. like "/home/folder/" or "/home/folder" and it should check only for the first time. and i don't have any static variable (i) in real code

Comment: Than do it before calling your recursion function. Don't mix between different logics

Comment: It also really helps when you ask a question that you want an answer to. Providing details after the fact like that often renders existing answers useless. If you want to do thing1 before thing2, then do it in its own function, and call it before thing2, instead of making thing2 know to call thing1. Don't overcomplicate things!

Comment: General advice: **don't use static variables in recursive functions.**  Your function won't work if you call it a second time from the outside world. Instead, pass `i` as an argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a helper function :

```
void recurfunc() {
   function2();
   helperRecurFunc();
}
```

where `helperRecurFunc()` is your original method without the call to `func2()`

Comment: any other thought, i don't want to create one more function

Comment: look at Jonathon Reinhart's solution.

Answer (score 8):

A trivial change to your code:

```
void recurfunc()         // * Remember to specify return type *
{
    static int i= 0;

    if (i==0)
        function2();     // called only the first time.

    i++;

    if(i>20)
        return;
    else
        recurfunc();
}
```

Comment: Sweet and simple solution :-)